# Azure Data Factory - ingest XML using source connector and store as CSV

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data set to fetch an XML document from a storage account. When I push that through and store it as a CSV (or JSON) *(edited for clarity)* in ADLS gen2 *(edit)*  using either a Mapping Data Flow or just a regular pipeline activity I end up with a file containing only the first line of the document. Anyone who has been through this that can give me a tip on what I'm doing wrong?
The XML map looks like this if that helps:

```xml
<xs:element name="SAMPLE_XML">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="record">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="LABEL" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="AUFNR" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SYSST" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STTXT" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="STTXU" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="AUART" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="QMNUM" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="QMTXT" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="TPLNR" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="BEARB" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="EQUNR" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="INGPR" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="VAPLZ" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="GSTRP" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="GLTRP" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ZZLTRMN" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PRIOK" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="REVNR" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ILART" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="KTEXT" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="UDATE_UTIME" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="VORNR" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="VSTTXT" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ARBPL" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ARBEI" type="xs:decimal" />
              <xs:element name="ISMNW" type="xs:decimal" />
              <xs:element name="AUFNT" />
              <xs:element name="PROID" />
              <xs:element name="ERNAM" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ERDAT" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="AENAM" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="AEDAT" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="LTXA1" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ANLZU" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="FSAVD" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="FSAVZ" type="xs:time" />
              <xs:element name="FSEDD" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="FSEDZ" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Where are you loading it to?

Comment: Azure Storage with hierarchical namespaces (a.k.a. Data Lake Store gen 2)

Comment: Have you tried using a collectionReference in the mapping settings of the copy activity?
Without one, it assumes data  has no complex types.  Use the collectionReference to iterate over the sequence and turn each element into a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MartinJaffer-MSFT in a comment to my question suggested I used a collectionReference in the mapping settings and that worked.
I hadn't used that as the description refers to JSON only. "Select or specify the JSONPath of a nested JSON array for cross-apply."
But yes, that worked as he said and problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!